# MobileFirst Platform Authentication failing on test server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We have a MFP V7 app that authenticates against a server without any problems when using the development server bundled with eclipse.  When we deploy to our test server, the application does not authenticate and in the server side trace we see the message.

The app is running on WAS 8.5.5.0 with a Liberty profile.

```
/usr/bin/java -version returns:
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.4.0.el6_6-x86_64 u75-b13)
```

Any ideas on how we can determine what is wrong with our configuration?

The stack trace looks like this:

```
[6/1/15 20:00:38:993 CDT] 00000130 id=com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter
  1 pushWebsphereSecurityContext Could not push websphere security context by reflection (server may not on WAS 7 or 8): com.ibm.ws.threadContext.ComponentMetaDataAccessorImpl; java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.threadContext.ComponentMetaDataAccessorImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1059)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.GatewayClassLoader.loadClass(GatewayClassLoader.java:127)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.WebsphereComponentMetaData.<init>(WebsphereComponentMetaData.java:23)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.pushWebsphereSecurityContext(AuthenticationFilter.java:797) 
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4499)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[6/1/15 20:00:38:994 CDT] 00000130 id=com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal
  1 set Set ProjectLocal: VA [6/1/15 20:00:38:994 CDT] 00000130 id=com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal 3 set java.lang.Throwable
    at com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal.set(BaseProjectLocal.java:56)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4499)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: As the error suggests, mention your application server type and version, as well as your Java version.

Comment: Idan, thanks.  I added the Liberty version and Java info.

Comment: Do not use was liberty 8.5.5.0; upgrade to 8.5.5.4 at minimum

Answer (score 0):

As per Idan's suggestion, Liberty was upgraded to 8.5.5.5 which helped.  We found that the issue was related to the default XSRF checking.  *For now* we are running with securityTest="wl_unprotected" and we can get past the issue.  Thanks as always to Idan.